# C# arraylist searching for objects property problems

Tags: c#, .net

I can't seem to see my error here. I know this isn't the best way to go at it but I'm obligated to use Arraylist.

Anyhow I know that my arraylist contains the right elements and I want to find out if the property Number for my Item class is the same as 'searchNr'.

If it is, I want to print out that element using ToString(). If I search for "107" (the Number property of my last element in the Arraylist, I do find it. Can't find any of the other number properties though. Can I use anything other than the If statement like (Equals)?

```
public void Search(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string searchNrString = searchTextBox.Text;
        int searchNr = Int32.Parse(searchNrString);


        foreach (Item product in item)    
        {                                 

            if (product.Number == searchNr)  //if we find the number
            {
                resultTextBox.Text = ((Item)product).ToString();    

            }
            else if ( product.Number != searchNr)    //if we don't find the number
            {
                string debug;
                debug = string.Format("Could not find the number {0}  arraylist :{1}", product.Number, item.Count); //debug här!
                resultTextBox.Text = debug;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where's the ArrayList? Also, what version of .NET are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a `break` statement to exit the loop once you find the desired item:

```
if (product.Number == searchNr)  //if we find the number
{
    resultTextBox.Text = ((Item)product).ToString();    
    break;
}
```

Otherwise you might find the item, but your loop continues till the end and thus the number no longer matches the subsequent items, causing your `else` statement to be evaluated. That is why you constantly appear to find the last element in your list (i.e., the "107" entry).

Comment: @user1040281 great! You should consider stepping through your code with the debugger. If you had set a breakpoint on your loop and walked through it the issue would've been apparent :)

Comment: Okay, thanks again will try that next time, Quite new at this and not that use to using the debugger :)